# Oracle Query Group By can't work as I wanted

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I group this data table :

```
username    module_id
testdavid   M0003
testdavid   M0001
testdavid   M0004
testdavid   M0002
```

to be

```
username    module_id
testdavid   M0003
            M0001
            M0004
            M0002
```

I using this query but still show testdavid in 4 row.
Here is my query :

```
SELECT USERNAME, MODULE_ID FROM SEIAPPS_T_ACCESS_MODULE WHERE USERNAME = 'testdavid' GROUP BY USERNAME, MODULE_ID;
```

Please help to solve this issued. Thanks

Comment: That should be done in the presentation layer, not in SQL.  Most reporting and UI layers have simple mechanisms to suppress duplicate values.  SQL has no such easy mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have to agree that this really should be handled in your presentation logic.  However, here is one approach using `LAG()`:

```
select 
  case 
    when lag(username,1) over (order by username) is null then username 
  end username, 
  module_id
from yourtable
where username = 'testdavid'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/62131/7)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you want to do this type of work in the application layer.  The result set does not conform to the "table" layout associated with SQL tables and result sets.

Nonetheless, this is possible:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY USERNAME ORDER BY MODULE_ID) = 1 THEN USERNAME
        END) as USERNAME, MODULE_ID
FROM SEIAPPS_T_ACCESS_MODUL
WHERE USERNAME = 'testdavid'
GROUP BY USERNAME, MODULE_ID
ORDER BY USERNAME, MODULE_ID;
```

In practice, if you just want to get a list of modules associated with a user name, why not put them all on one row?

```
select username, listagg(module_id, ',') within group (order by module_id)
from (select username, module_id
      from SEIAPPS_T_ACCESS_MODUL
      where username = 'testdavid'
      group by username, module_id
     ) um
group by username;
```